# split date and time collide with space between them in bash

Tags: bash

from my wp cli I receive a date format like this :

YYYY-mm-ddHH-mm-ss for example : 2020-02-2514:24:25

I would like to convert it to timestamp but the format date is incorrect.

I would like to split the date and time with space between them but I have no idea to do that currently.

with regex may be but I just seen how to replace space and I am a nooby with bash regex.

thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: What is your expected output for the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **cut**

```
root@a036fb1c94fa:~# DATE=$(echo "2020-02-2514:24:25" | cut -b-10)
root@a036fb1c94fa:~# TIME=$(echo "2020-02-2514:24:25" | cut -b11-)
root@a036fb1c94fa:~# TIMESTAMP=$(date -d "$DATE $TIME" +"%s")
root@a036fb1c94fa:~# echo $TIME
14:24:25
root@a036fb1c94fa:~# echo $DATE
2020-02-25
root@a036fb1c94fa:~# echo $TIMESTAMP
1582637065
```

**Explanation:**

```
echo "2020-02-2514:24:25" | cut -b-10
```

echo the string and cut it before the 10th byte

```
echo "2020-02-2514:24:25" | cut -b11-
```

echo the string and cut it from the 11th byte until the end

```
echo date -d "$DATE $TIME" +"%s"
```

give the right format to unix date command, with +"%s" to get its timestamp

Comment: Thank you @franzisk. that is ok

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any regex. You can select substrings in bash.

If the variable `wpdate` contains the string returned by wp cli, the corresponding timestamp can be put into the variable `timestamp` as follows:

```
timestamp=$(date '+%s' --date "${wpdate:0:10} ${wpdate:10:8}")
```

Explanation: `${wpdate:10:8}` means the substring of `wpdate` starting at position 10 and containing 8 chars.

Comment: Pierre François I tryied your suggestion and it does not work in my case. In fact, my wp cli return a list of date, precisely several date of comments. I convert characters into array by using space separated. so the wpdate is not just a variable but a part of array. wpdate[@] that contain one date.

Comment: You should have said that in your post. Assuming there are two elements in the array (which you don't mention), the solution is very simple: `timestamp=$(date '+%s' --date "${wpdate[0]} ${wpdate[1]}")`